# Como poner una imagen sesgada y en perspetiva por medio de CSS y adaptable a la imagen adjunta?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-transform

Como puedo acomodar la imagen para que se adapte al celular

[[image]

```css
#capa1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 127px;
    left: 118px;
    transform: perspective(321px) rotateY(46deg) rotateX(70deg) rotateZ(-21deg) scale(1) translate(-119px, 77px);
    height: 153px;
    width: 217px;
    background-color:red;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 0;
}

#cont1 {
    /* position: relative; */
    border-radius: 30px;
    z-index: -12;
    height: 659px;
    /* transform: rotate(-3deg); */
    transform: skew(11deg, -2deg);
}
```

```html
  <div id="cont1">
      <div id="capa1"></div>
  </div>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SibI.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SibI.png)